# Minimum number of jumps to reach end dynamic programmig

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-programming

Given an array, verify from the first element how many steps are needed to reach the end.

Example: arr = [1, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 6, 7, 0, 7, 9]

1 -> 3 -> 8  (this is the shortest path)

3 steps.

So far, i have this code from geeks for geeks:

```
def jumpCount(x, n): 
  jumps = [0 for i in range(n)] 

  if (n == 0) or (x[0] == 0): 
      return float('inf') 

  jumps[0] = 0


  for i in range(1, n): 
      jumps[i] = float('inf')   
      for j in range(i): 
          if (i <= j + x[j]) and (jumps[j] != float('inf')): 
              jumps[i] = min(jumps[i], jumps[j] + 1) 
              break                 
  return jumps[n-1]     

def jumps(x):
  n = len(x)
  return jumpCount(x,n) 

x = [1, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 6, 7, 0, 7, 9]

print(jumps(x))
```

But I want to print out what numbers made the shortest path (1-3-8). How can I adapt the code to do it?

I tried to create a list of j's but since 5 is tested in the loop, it's appended too.

Link to the problem: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential idea is that you need an auxiliary structure to help you keep track of the minimum path. Those type of structures are usually called "backpointers" (you could call them in our case "forwardpointers" since we are going forward, duh). My code solves the problem recursively, but the same could be done iteratively. The strategy is as follows:

```
jumps_vector = [ 1, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 6, 7, 0, 7, 9 ]

"""
fwdpointers holds the relative jump size to reach the minimum number of jumps
for every component of the original vector
"""
fwdpointers = {}

def jumps( start ):
    if start == len( jumps_vector ) - 1:
        # Reached the end
        return 0
    if start > len( jumps_vector ) - 1:
        # Cannot go through that path
        return math.inf
    if jumps_vector[ start ] == 0:
        # Cannot go through that path (infinite loop with itself)
        return math.inf

    # Get the minimum in a traditional way
    current_min = jumps( start + 1 )
    fwdpointers[ start ] = start + 1
    for i in range( 2, jumps_vector[ start ] + 1 ):
        aux_min = jumps( start + i )
        if current_min > aux_min:
            # Better path. Update minimum and fwdpointers
            current_min = aux_min
            # Store the (relative!) index of where I jump to
            fwdpointers[ start ] = i

    return 1 + current_min
```

In this case, the variable `fwdpointers` stores the relative indexes of where I jump to. For instance, `fwdpointers[ 0 ] = 1`, since I will jump to the adjacent number, but `fwdpointers[ 1 ] = 2` since I will jump two numbers the next jump.

Having done that, then it's only a matter of postprocessing things a bit on the `main()` function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    min_jumps = jumps( 0 )
    print( min_jumps )

    # Holds the index of the jump given such that
    # the sequence of jumps are the minimum
    i = 0
    # Remember that the contents of fwdpointers[ i ] are the relative indexes
    # of the jump, not the absolute ones
    print( fwdpointers[ 0 ] )
    while i in fwdpointers and i + fwdpointers[ i ] < len( jumps_vector ):
        print( jumps_vector[ i + fwdpointers[ i ] ] )
        # Get the index of where I jump to
        i += fwdpointers[ i ]
        jumped_to = jumps_vector[ i ]
```

I hope this answered your question.

---

EDIT: I think the iterative version is more readable:

```
results = {}
backpointers = {}
def jumps_iter():
    results[ 0 ] = 0
    backpointers[ 0 ] = -1
    for i in range( len( jumps_vector ) ):
        for j in range( 1, jumps_vector[ i ] + 1 ):
            if ( i + j ) in results:
                results[ i + j ] = min( results[ i ] + 1, results[ i + j ] )
                if results[ i + j ] == results[ i ] + 1:
                    # Update where I come from
                    backpointers[ i + j ] = i
            elif i + j < len( jumps_vector ):
                results[ i + j ] = results[ i ] + 1
                # Set where I come from
                backpointers[ i + j ] = i

    return results[ len( jumps_vector ) - 1 ]
```

And the postprocessing:

```
i = len( jumps_vector ) - 1
print( jumps_vector[ len( jumps_vector ) - 1 ], end = " " )
while backpointers[ i ] >= 0:
    print( jumps_vector[ backpointers[ i ] ], end = " " )
    i = backpointers[ i ]
print()
```